# proving well-defined functions

Tags: functions

Let A and B be non-empty sets and *f* : **A** → **B** be a bijection. Consider the map $\phi : S_A → S_B$ that sends $\sigma$ to ${f} \circ {\sigma} \circ {f^{-1}}$. Show that $\phi$ is a well-defined function.

Now, I don't have an idea proving a function to be well-defined. Someone help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... as far as I can see the only thing that could *prevent* $\phi$ from being well-defined whould be if

1. there is some $\sigma\in S_A$ for which $\phi(\sigma)$ is not defined,
2. there is some $\sigma\in S_A$ for which two different values for $\phi(\sigma)$ match the specification, or
3. there is some $\sigma\in S_A$ where $\phi(\sigma)\notin S_B$.

All of these would be easy enough to check, but it can feel a bit like there's nothing really happening because $\phi$ is so *obviously* well-defined.

The "check that $f$ is well-defined" trope is more often used when the function is not defined by an explicit recipe for how to make $f(x)$ given $x$, but by some abstract property that you require $f(x)$ to have. Then you'd need to prove that one and only one possible value of the function has this property for each $x$.

Comment: I think that the less obvious condition to check is $\phi ( \sigma ) \in S_B$ (maybe for a beginner it's not so obvious).

Comment: so how do i actually prove it? I really have no idea

Comment: What does $S_A$ denote  in this context?

Comment: @user254665: I take it to be symmetric group on $A$, that is, the set of all bijections $A\to A$.

Comment: @eeeeeee: As I said, there's essentially nothing to prove. Just observing that your function has a definite definition for the value of $\phi(\sigma)$ once $\sigma$ is given will do it.